# Cut off view from bottom corner

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I have a layout which i want to cut off its bottom corner to slash like cut , i have already tried using ShapeAppearanceModel but did not get the desired result , i would appreciate any help , Thank you

- This is my code to shape corner

```
 val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, 36f)
            .build()

        val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
        ViewCompat.setBackground(shapedLayout, shapeDrawable)
```

- This is desired result ( basically cut off white layout from bottom , not the black layout )

[image]

Comment: Please provide your xml layout

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to cut the **top right** of the black area? The background of the view behind it will need to be white too (if you're talking about making the white area look like a speech bubble, which you suggested in another comment)

Comment: @cactustictacs Yeah basically i want the cut corner from white area to overlap the black area

Comment: It's not really anything to do with the white area - Views are rectangular, so if you want to make that area white, that's part of **the black View's area** and you need to change *its* top-right corner. You can't make the white area overlap (Views are rectangular remember) - you can only cut the corner off the black part, and whatever's behind it will  show through (*Bhavnik*'s answer shows you how). If you don't have a white View/background behind it, you'll have to add one - you might actually want to make the white area extend lower, so the black part is on top of it

Answer (score 1):

@Taki,

I performed a small demo at my end through XML and it works as per your requirement.
Please have a look at it and let me know whether it is helpful or not.

### Your layout file :

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.BottomCornerCut"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/glStart"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/glEnd" />

<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/layoutTwo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.TopCornerCut"
    android:background="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/glStart"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/glEnd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutOne"/>
```

### Your style (put corner family and size as per your requirement.) :

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.TopCornerCut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">25dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.BottomCornerCut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">25dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
</style>
```

### Output :

[image: Output]

Comment: @Bhavnit , I appreciate the time you took to respond but that's not exactly what i want as shown above ( white space is a layout and black one is a different , i want to cut on white layout which overcross the black layout , something like https://uxwing.com/chat-message-icon/ )  , Thank you in advance